# Which one should I use to free the COM object?

Tags: delphi

I have a COM class, which looks something like this:

```
  TRadioTracer = class(TAutoObject, IRadioTracer)
```

Now, I can do

```
var
   obj: TRadioTracer;
begin
   obj := TRadioTracer.Create;
   // some other code
   obj.Free;
   obj.CleanupInstance;
   obj.FreeInstance;
end;
```

These are from System.pas

```
procedure TObject.FreeInstance;
begin
  CleanupInstance;
  _FreeMem(Pointer(Self));
end;

procedure TObject.CleanupInstance;
{$IFDEF PUREPASCAL}
var
  ClassPtr: TClass;
  InitTable: Pointer;
begin
{$IFDEF WEAKREF}
  _CleanupInstance(Self);
{$ENDIF}
  ClassPtr := ClassType;
  repeat
    InitTable := PPointer(PByte(ClassPtr) + vmtInitTable)^;
    if InitTable <> nil then
      _FinalizeRecord(Self, InitTable);
    ClassPtr := ClassPtr.ClassParent;
  until ClassPtr = nil;
  TMonitor.Destroy(Self);
end;
{$ELSE !PUREPASCAL}
// some other code

procedure TObject.Free;
begin
// under ARC, this method isn't actually called since the compiler translates
// the call to be a mere nil assignment to the instance variable, which then calls _InstClear
{$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

Which one should I use to free the COM object?

Comment: Don't use any of those. Why would you think that you should ever call CleanupInstance and FreeInstance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the interface type to store a reference to the object. It will be destroyed as soon as there is no reference to it left:

```
var
   obj: IRadioTracer;
begin
   obj := TRadioTracer.Create;
   obj.DoThings;
end; // obj will be freed here automatically
```

When you use the COM-Object in a different application or via a `TAutoObjectFactory` then you will only know the interface type. You have no access then to the concrete class type. That's an additional reason why to prefer the interface type here over the class type.

In case you are using the class type to reference the object you need to call `Free` to destroy it.

Comment: thanks... how about if I do want to access the concrete class type? should I use Free?

Comment: @Doctor Usually you don't do that. Usually you use the interface.

Comment: usually, i put the .Free at try-finally.. if i use interface, will the inteface be freed when there is an exception？

Comment: Yes it will. Read up on reference counting.

Comment: @DoctorLai: Yes. The interface's reference count is decremented when the interface variable goes out of scope, including when exceptions are raised.  When the last reference to the object gets released, the object frees itself.